# Power bi Admin Portal issue Not able to access admin portal

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-fabric

I am not able to access the admin portal of power bi even after the purchase of power bi pro license can anyone help me to fix this problem ??[Power bi admin portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GX07.png)

As I mentioned the details of the problem that even after the purchase of the pro license I am not able to access the admin portal so my expection is that my problem should get the solution I should able to access the admin portal and all permissions

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone in the organization would have access to Admin portal.

The one who already has access can add you in the access :

Go to the Power BI admin portal (https://admin.powerbi.com/).

Sign in using your Power BI admin account credentials.

Click on the "Admins" tab in the left-hand navigation.

In the Admins tab, you will see a list of all the users who have been granted Power BI admin permissions in your organization. You can see their names, email addresses, and the date they were added as Power BI admins.

You can also use the search bar at the top of the page to search for specific users by name or email address.

By using the Power BI admin portal, you can easily see who in your organization has Power BI admin permissions, allowing you to better manage and control access to your Power BI resources.

Comment: I am not getting your point where should I login the link you provided is not working did I want to login on the microsoft  365 admin portal or some where else ??

Comment: What I mean is, not everyone would have access on admin portal. You would have to reach out to your tenant admin to get those details

Comment: No it's not working any other solution??